# Change conditions using loop and array in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement

i have and old script in python, where in

```
if __name__ == '__main__': <br>
```

We call arguments of functions. And if it argument equals some string we should call function. 
Old code.

```
if sys.argv[1] == 'add':
    sys.exit(add(db, usr))
if sys.argv[1] == 'rem':
    sys.exit(rem(db, usr))
if sys.argv[1] == 'rmusr':
    sys.exit(rmusr(db, usr))
```

At the first time, i thought about "switch case", but how i find out, python does not have it. And i tried to loop and array. 
Can i use it on this ? Sorry, i started learn python, 2 hours ago. But it is very interesting, and i hope, that you can help me.

```
 actions = ['add','rem','rmusr']
    for a in actions:
    if sys.argv[1] == 'a':
        sys.exit(a(db, usr))
```

Is it correct ? How i find out, we should not call variables with "$". Please help.

Comment: The line `if sys.argv[1] == 'a':` compares the user input to the character `a`. I don't think this is what you want. Try removing the single quotes so that you compare `argv[1]` to the value of the variable `a`, not the character `'a'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the functions to the dictionary and then use the user-input string to retrieve the function:

```
actions = {
    'add': add,
    'rem': rem,
    'rmusr': rmusr,
}

action = sys.argv[1]

if action in actions:
    sys.exit(actions[action](db, usr))
```

Comment: but what about my way ? it should not work ? if i want to use loop ?

Comment: Your example mixes up the function variable (`a`) with a similar string (`'a'`): they're not the same. There's no need to add a loop, since the `in` operator in my example does all the checking you need.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary:

```
actions = {'add': add, 'rem': rem, 'rmusr': rmusr}

try:
    sys.exit(actions[sys.argv[1]](db, usr))
except KeyError:
   pass
   # or whatever you need to do for an invalid action
```

Answer (score 0):

your code could be right but there is a typo on it.

```
actions = ['add','rem','rmusr']
for a in actions:
    if sys.argv[1] == 'a':
        sys.exit(a(db, usr))
```

I think It's better using in:

```
actions = ['add','rem','rmusr']
if sys.argv[1] in actions:
    sys.exit(sys.argv[1](db, usr))
```