# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable in python script

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement

yes, i am an author of this [Change conditions using loop and array in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43505938/change-conditions-using-loop-and-array-in-python)

So, i am trying to change conditions from this:

```
if sys.argv[1] == 'add':
    sys.exit(add(db, usr))
if sys.argv[1] == 'rem':
    sys.exit(rem(db, usr))
if sys.argv[1] == 'rmusr':
    sys.exit(rmusr(db, usr))
```

I am trying to change these conditions at list with loop

From answers of other developers, i used this:

```
actions = ['add','rem','rmusr']
if sys.argv[1] in actions:
    sys.exit(sys.argv[1](db, usr))
```

But, when i am trying to check it function, i have this

```
  File "sql.py", line 25, in <module>
    sys.exit(sys.argv[1](db, usr))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I can't understand, where i have an error ?

Comment: They used a dictionary in the linked question, you're using  a list

Comment: because i think, that list should work too, but i don't understand, why it does not work

Comment: You have a list of strings not a list of functions

Comment: The reason it's not working is because your array is a list of strings, not functions. So when you do `sys.argv[1](db, usr)`, you're actually literally doing this: `"rem"(db, usr)`. The solution is to change the array of strings to an array of functions

Comment: so ... only dict ?

Comment: yes-yes-yes. i understand. it works. yeah =)))

Comment: thanks guys, how i did not see it ?)

Answer (score 1):

Your error specifically is because you're trying to call a method with the signature string(db, usr).  The line sys.argv[1] refers to the **string** located in the **list** argv in your **program** sys. Strings are not callable; your code is the equivalent of:

```
"add"(db, usr)  # add is not a variable name.
```

The answer to the other question used a dictionary whose lookup-keys were associated with the specific methods of the same name, so they didn't call the string so much as lookup the method from the dictionary using the string.

Answer (score 0):

In order to call the function named by `sys.argv[1]` it needs to be fetched first. For example:

```
def add(x,y):
    return x + y

def mul(x,y):
    return x * y

def perform(action, x, y):
    # action is a string containing a function name ("add" or "mul").
    # globals() contains the accessible members, along with the functions.
    return globals()[action](x, y)
```

In the context of the original code:

```
actions = ['add','rem','rmusr']
if sys.argv[1] in actions:
    func = globals()[sys.argv[1]]
    sys.exit(func(db, usr))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
# specify the function to call for each command:
# (note: the lookup key is a string, but the value is a function reference)
actions = {'add': add, 'rem': rem, 'rmusr': rmusr}
cmd = sys.argv[1]
# check if it's in the dictionary's keys
if cmd in actions:
    # lookup the function to call
    func = actions[cmd]
    # call the function
    sys.exit(func(db, usr))
```

Or this is less verbose, but also less specific. It uses the fact that all defined functions are listed by name in the `globals()` dictionary.

```
# list of all allowed commands:
actions = ['add', 'rem', 'rmusr']
cmd = sys.argv[1]
# check if it's allowed
if cmd in actions:
    # lookup the function by name in the globals() dictionary
    func = globals()[cmd]
    # call the function
    sys.exit(func(db, usr))
```

Answer (score 0):

`sys.argv[1]` is of type `str` (a string), and a string is **not** a function. So when you try to execute `sys.argv[1](db, usr)`, you are literally trying to execute a string as if it were a function, which is not allowed.

What you *can* do, however, is lookup the function by using the value inside `sys.argv[1]`. You can do this multiple ways. One way would be to lookup the function by using `globals()`, which returns a dictionary of the names of the functions mapped to the actual function itself.

For example:

Lets say you execute your program with this command: `python myScript.py argument1`. That would mean that `sys.argv[1]` would have the value `"argument1"`. Then you would take this value and lookup the function in the dictionary returned by `globals()` (or you could use `locals()` if you are in the same scope as the function you are calling):

```
sys.exit(globals()[sys.argv[1]](db, usr))
```

The other way would be to create this dictionary yourself:

```
actions = {'add': add, 'rem': rem, 'rmusr': rmusr}
if sys.argv[1] in actions:
    sys.exit(actions[sys.argv[1]](db, usr))
```

Comment: `actions` needs curly braces `{ }` to create a dictionary; it's currently a list (actually, you'll get a syntax error).

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to change those.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/argparse.html
Using the argparse you have morze flexability using the command lines args. You can easily use the if statement  if an arg is used im the command lines.